# How to use grep with quotes inside a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to use the following pattern inside a shell script eg. I want to use the following:

```
grep ^"#" $fn | grep -v NM$ > $op
```

but inside `bash` script.  The problem is normally `bash` considers everything after the "#" as a comment.  If i use

```
grep ^"\#" $fn
```

I think it changes the meaning.  I am a newbie.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `#` is not a comment if it's inside quotes.

Comment: The carot (`^`) belongs inside the quotes.

Comment: The carot at the beginning matches to the beginning of the line, e.g.: `ls | grep ^d` lists all files beginning with d.

Comment: @Cosades Yep. I would normally put it inside the quotes if I'm using quotes. In your example, `ls | grep "^d"`.

Comment: I was trying to match all the lines that begin with a "#" character.  On the command line "#" is not a comment, but inside a shell-script, I think it becomes a comment?  Am i missing something?

Comment: It is not a comment, but backslash-escaping it is harmless.

Comment: @tripleee: backslash-escaping it inside quotes doesn't work. I'm not sure what your definition of harmless is

Comment: What's your definition of "doesn't work"? `grep ^"\#"` does what I expect here (GNU Grep 2.5.3).

Comment: @Barmar, i think your solution is correct.  I realized i was doing something else wrong.  The script works.  Should I move to close this question?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities:

```
grep '^#' $fn
```

or

```
grep "^#" $fn
```

or

```
grep ^\# $fn
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example which I saved as `foo.sh`

```
echo "#"
echo '#'  # this is a comment
echo '\#'
```

when run as `sh foo.sh` this is what is printed out

```
#
#
\#
```